# Dynamic range of an excel model

Tags: excel, graph, data-modeling

I'm working on an excel model that consists of stock data. I want the model to have a graph as output. As the length of the data is not always the same I want to have a dynamic range. I want the formula to take the data until the last colum with data. Is it possible to introduce such a patterm?

I tried `a2:end` but this won't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. I would like you to introduce you on how to ask a question as a [mcve]. Please do some proper research and then come back to us *if* you didnt succeed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, if I understand correctly, is simply use "A:A".
It will ignore blank cells (And headers of course) and will simply take the data in column A.

If you want to do it in a programmatic way, such as [vba macros](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_excel_macros.htm), you can also use:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

This will return how many rows have data in your current sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put data into pivot table and make pivot graph. This is the fastest way by my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your data source into an Excel Table (aka ListObject) using the Ctrl + T shortcut or Insert > Table from the ribbon. Excel Tables are dynamic named ranges that Excel maintains for you, and any formulas, charts, or PivotTables that point at them will therefore always have the latest data in them. (Note that PivotTables will need to be refreshed before the data shows up).

Answer (score 0):

you can generate dynamic graphs by using Offset function. First of all you need to define range for the graph. For that you need to identify last cell address which you want to populate in graph & it should be dynamic.

Then by using Index function you can generate dynamic graph as per data.